# Why is PHP not replacing the variable in string?

Tags: php

I dont get why this simple line of code does not work:

```
<?php
$someVariable = 0;
echo 'SomeVariable is $someVariable';
?>
```

It is printing out "SomeVariable is $someVariable" as opposed to the number 0. Is there something I am missing or some configuration option I have to enable?

Comment: Because you're using single quotes instead of double. Switch to `"SomeVariable is $someVariable"`

Comment: This is clearly spelled out in the manual, as well as many other StackOverflow questions.

Comment: Here's [the link to documentation](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) where this is defined. _"Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings."_

Comment: downvoted because i can't believe this got a 5votes answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is because you need to use double quote instead.
php will not convert variables to their values when surrounded by single quotes

```
<?php
$someVariable = 0;
echo "SomeVariable is $someVariable";
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

the single quote's doesn't process in PHP, you must use variable in double quotes.

Comment: A fact in most popular languages: single quotes are for literal strings, only double quotes allow variable interpolation.