# Dynamic Location header PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is PHP not replacing the variable in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317743/why-is-php-not-replacing-the-variable-in-string)

I would like to have my PHP redirect headers dynamic. Currently I have:

```
header('Location:message.php?ref=conversation&conv=$conv_id')
```

But that redirects the user to:

```
doamin.com/message.php?ref=conversation&conv="$conv_id"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The question has already been answered, but also note that HTTP/1.1 requires absolute URIs (even though modern clients are smart enough to translate relative URIs). See [Header Field Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30).

Answer (score 3):

You are putting a variable in single quotes, change to double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Change it into this:

```
header("Location:message.php?ref=conversation&conv=$conv_id");
```

Or this:

```
header('Location:message.php?ref=conversation&conv=' . $conv_id);
```

(I prefer the latter, but that's just a personal thing.)

The thing is that in php, it parses variables inside a string if you use double quotes and doesn't if you use single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

anything in single quote behave like a string

so

```
header('Location:message.php?ref=conversation&conv=$conv_id') will not work
```

should be

```
header("Location:message.php?ref=conversation&conv=$conv_id")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not much, you should pass the var into the string

```
header("Location:message.php?ref=conversation&conv=" . $conv_id)
```

Comment: No point concatenating with double quotes. Just interpolate.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of these two:

```
header("Location:message.php?ref=conversation&conv=$conv_id");
```

OR

```
header('Location:message.php?ref=conversation&conv='.$conv_id);
```

you shouldn't place the variable in the single quote `'`. place it in the double `"` quote, will work