# Bug encountered while Executing .exe file from a Php script

Tags: php, exe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is PHP not replacing the variable in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317743/why-is-php-not-replacing-the-variable-in-string)

I have been trying to execute this line `echo exec('hi.exe $file',$results,$status);` from Php. where the value assigned to $file is the filename **hi.txt** (i.e. $file = hi.txt).

But each time i try to run my code with the same line, its showing error as `$file file not found` where as if i run the same `hi.exe hi.txt` in a command prompt its working.

And also if i try to run the same line with the filename instead of a variable from php     i.e.`exec('hi.exe hi.txt',$results,$status)`, the browser keeps executing for long time without giving the output.

Please someone tell me where i am going wrong!

Comment: Do you mean to assign `$file = "hi.txt"` rather than `$filename`?

Comment: Yes... sorry by mistake i typed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using single quotes, instead of double quotes.  Change `echo exec('hi.exe $file',$results,$status);` to:

```
echo exec("hi.exe $file",$results,$status);
```

or use a dot, like this:

```
echo exec('hi.exe '.$file,$results,$status);
```

In PHP, using single quotes won't turn `$file` into `hi.txt`; it just stays as the literal string, "$file".  Use double quotes or dot concatenation to actually expand `$file` into `hi.txt`

Comment: Thanks... using double quotes

Comment: but why does the browser takes so much time to execute the .exe? any suggestions?

Comment: The browser does not execute the exe, the server does.  You will have to see how the exe is performing on the server

Comment: oh... how can we do that can you attach some links.. sorry i m completely new to this field.

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes don't expand variables. You probably mean:

```
echo exec("hi.exe $file",$results,$status);
```

Comment: "Interpolate" would be the word to use here rather than "expand" but +1 regardless. (The process is called variable interpolation.)

Comment: i need to expand the variable, because i am taking the $file variable as an user input.