# Count a Variable

Tags: php, string, csv, count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is PHP not replacing the variable in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317743/why-is-php-not-replacing-the-variable-in-string)

I cannot seem to get this right, I want to do a linecount of the lines in a CSV, and the CSV is taken from the URL of the page i.e. it's a query string.

```
$file= $_GET['file'];
$linecount = count(file(' $file ')) -1;
```

Basically the first function is to get the URL of the file from the query string in the URL and then the second function is to count the number of lines in the CSV. Please help, it will be very much appreciated.

Also note that the -1 is to skip the first line from the CSV as that is all headers.

Comment: Variables don't work in single quoted strings. (And the extraneous spaces wouldn't help either.)

Comment: What if you just leave `$file` as an argument without the quotes?

Comment: `' $file '` is a string with `" $file "` as content. However, seems like you are going to open your server for everyone. Never access something from outside, before you validated it!

Answer (score 1):

Variables in single quotes do not expand so your code is literally looking for a file named `' $file '`. Just do `var_dump(' $file ');` and you will see what I mean. Then try the same with double quotes. But I don't see that you need the quotes at all-- `count(file($file)) -1`

What you do need to do is validate that `$_GET` parameter before loading it. What you have just screams "local file inclusion" to me.

http://hakipedia.com/index.php/Local_File_Inclusion

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = $_GET['file'];
$linecount = count(file($file)) - 1;
```