# Reading and writting from an ini file (Config_Lite)

Tags: php, pear, ini

Alright so I've read around for a little while and so far the best solution I've found so far is: [How to read and write to an ini file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695145/how-to-read-and-write-to-an-ini-file-with-php)

I've installed the pear package. included the required file initiated the class. as shown at:
https://github.com/pear/Config_Lite/blob/master/docs/examples

However i am having troubles getting the variable.

this is my ini file:

```
[Account]
acct1.UserName = something1
acct1.Password = something2
acct1.Signature = something3
acct1.AppId = something4
# Subject is optional and is required only in case of third party authorization 
acct1.Subject =
```

This is what i tried so far:

```
$config = new Config_Lite('$filename');
echo $config->get('Account', 'acct1.UserName');
```

It did not work and returned an error.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Shouldn't you get an error for the invalid filename?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is PHP not replacing the variable in string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317743/why-is-php-not-replacing-the-variable-in-string)

Comment: Mario thanks for opening my eyes. the filename was quoted bah

Answer (score 1):

You can use `acct1[UserName]=something1` instead of `acct1.UserName=something1` and then in PHP access it by the following code:

```
[Account]
acct1[UserName]=something1

$config = new Config_Lite("$filename");
$config_acc = $config -> get('Account','acct1');
echo $config_db['UserName'];
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer to avoid deletion

Answer (score -3):

you can use Zend_config_init

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.config.adapters.ini.html

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.config.writer.introduction.html